# Flags: get Action after a user flagged a specific number of nodes?

Tags: flags, actions

I would like the users of my site to choose a specific number of nodes. After this they should see, to which taxonomy term these nodes belong to.

I have already found the [flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module as well as [flag limiter](https://drupal.org/project/flag_limiter) module. I have put the limit to 12 (This is the amount of nodes the user should be able to choose).

Now I would like that the user is redirected to a new page (where he can see the belongig taxonomy terms to his flagged nodes - this I can manage to create with views), after he flagged the 12th node.

Could anyone help me, how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Tabea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can able to detect limit has reached using [hook_flag_flag](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!flag!flag.api.php/function/hook_flag_flag/7) hook exposed by flag module..

Flag Limiter module uses the same logic to detect the limit as you can see the below code

```
function flag_limiter_flag_flag($flag, $entity_id, $account, $flagging) {
  // Get the flag limits.
  $flag_limit = variable_get('flag_limiter_' . $flag->name . '_value', 0);
  $peritem_limit = variable_get('flag_limiter_' . $flag->name . '_peritem_value', 0);

  if ($flag_limit) {
    $user_flags = flag_limiter_get_user_flags($account->uid, $flag->fid);
    if (count($user_flags) > $flag_limit) {
      $unflag = flag('unflag', $flag->name, $entity_id, $account, TRUE);
      if ($unflag) {
        drupal_set_message(t("You've already signed up @num times", array('@num' => $flag_limit)), 'error');
      } else {
        drupal_set_message(t('Fail limiter operation'), 'status', FALSE);
      }
    }
  }

  if ($peritem_limit) {
    $flagging_data = flag_get_counts($flag->entity_type, $entity_id, TRUE);
    if ($flagging_data[$flagging->flag_name] > $peritem_limit) {
      $unflag_item = flag('unflag', $flag->name, $entity_id, $account, TRUE);
      if ($unflag_item) {
        drupal_set_message(t("The event already signed up @num times", array('@num' => $peritem_limit)), 'error');
      } else {
        drupal_set_message(t('Fail limiter operation'), 'status', FALSE);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can implement same hook in your custom module to redirect user to the page you want.. You can use [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) function to redirect user..

```
function YOURMODULENAME_flag_flag($flag, $entity_id, $account, $flagging) {
  if ($flag_limit) {
    $user_flags = flag_limiter_get_user_flags($account->uid, $flag->fid);
    if (count($user_flags) >= $flag_limit) {
      drupal_goto('path');
    }
  }
}
```

writing custom module [instructions](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7) ..

- Create a folder called "custom" inside sites/all/modules
- Create a folder called "myflaglimit" inside sites/all/modules/custom/
- Create a file called "myflaglimit.info" inside "myflaglimit" folder create above.
- Put in below code and save file

Below code goes into myflaglimit.info file..

```
name = My Flag Limit
description = Provides a redirect on reaching limit.
core = 7.x
package = Custom
dependencies[] = flag_limiter
```

Your logic goes into .module file

- Create a file called myflaglimit.module file inside myflaglimit folder you have create with below code
- You extend drupal function using [hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7) which are nothing but functions which starts with modulename_hook

use below code inside module file

```
<?php
function myflaglimit_flag_flag($flag, $entity_id, $account, $flagging) {
  if ($flag_limit) {
    $user_flags = flag_limiter_get_user_flags($account->uid, $flag->fid);
    if (count($user_flags) >= $flag_limit) {
      drupal_goto('path');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I am beginner with drupal. Could you please tell me, in which file I have to load this code-function or if I have to create a new file (in this case: in which folder do I have to upload it?).

Comment: Updated answer with full details :-)